# HTML not responsive after making width 100%

Tags: html, css

I have some HTML code inside a tag named `#clock` with this CSS:

```
#clock {
  width: 100%;
  top: 25%;
  margin: 0 auto 36px auto;
}
```

The width was 480px however I thought if i changed it to 100% it would resize with the screen width however this is not working.

I created a fiddle here with the full example, what am I doing wrong? How can I make this responsive to fit on all screens as im lost?

https://jsfiddle.net/axtdswb1/

thank you in advance

Comment: Are you trying to upscale the whole clock based on the parent width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of all the positioning - you don't need it here. Use margins instead in order to move your content upon changing the viewport (if needed). `<div>`s are 100% wide by default. Also you might want to check this [Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Well, since we only know that you want it all to be responsive and fit the viewport, check this out:

```css
#clock, .time {
  display: flex;
}
#clock {
  margin: 0 auto 36px auto;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-content: center;
}
.time {
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
}
.display {
  letter-spacing: 3.2rem;
}
.bit {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  margin: 8px;
  background: #f36f25;
  box-shadow: 0 0 16px #f36f25;
  transition: all .5s ease-out;
}
.bit.blank {
  background: black;
  box-shadow: none;
}
@media only screen
and (min-width: 320px)
and (max-device-width: 768px)
and (orientation: landscape)
{
  #clock {
    top: 15%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="clock">
          <div class="time hours">
            <div class="column">
              <div class="bit blank"></div>
              <div class="bit blank"></div>
              <div class="bit h5"></div>
              <div class="bit h4"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
              <div class="bit h3"></div>
              <div class="bit h2"></div>
              <div class="bit h1"></div>
              <div class="bit h0"></div>
            </div>
            <h2 class="display"></h2>
          </div>
          <div class="time minutes">
            <div class="column">
              <div class="bit blank"></div>
              <div class="bit m6"></div>
              <div class="bit m5"></div>
              <div class="bit m4"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
              <div class="bit m3"></div>
              <div class="bit m2"></div>
              <div class="bit m1"></div>
              <div class="bit m0"></div>
            </div>
            <h2 class="display"></h2>
          </div>
          <div class="time seconds">
            <div class="column">
              <div class="bit blank"></div>
              <div class="bit s6"></div>
              <div class="bit s5"></div>
              <div class="bit s4"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
              <div class="bit s3"></div>
              <div class="bit s2"></div>
              <div class="bit s1"></div>
              <div class="bit s0"></div>
            </div>
            <h2 class="display"></h2>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure of the final outcome you're looking for. However, at the very least, you should just add `flex: 1;` to `.time` class.

Your current `css` isn't specifying how much space each of the flex children should occupy. They end up stacking to the left.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a percentage-based width makes the width relative to the **parent** element. This parent element needs to have a width defined itself. The direct parent can have a relative width, but at *some* point in the hierarchy you need a fixed width. Unfortunately, neither `<body>` nor `<html>` take on a fixed `width` by default.

Considering your `#clock` sits directly under `<body>`, you can make use of **[viewport-sized typography](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/)** with `width: 100vw` to state that the the `#clock` element should take up `100%` of the width of the viewport.

Keep in mind that if you're making use of the full viewport, you'll also want to override the default `margin: 8px` on `<body>` with `margin: 0`:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#clock {
  width: 100vw;
}
```

This can be seen in the following example:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#clock,
.time {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#clock {
  width: 100vw;
  top: 25%;
  margin: 0 auto 36px auto;
}

.time.minutes {
  left: 32px;
}

.time.seconds {
  left: 64px;
}

.column {
  top: 0;
}

.display {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -36px;
  left: 35px;
  letter-spacing: 3.2rem;
}

.bit {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  margin: 8px;
  background: #f36f25;
  box-shadow: 0 0 16px #f36f25;
  transition: all .5s ease-out;
}

.bit.blank {
  background: black;
  box-shadow: none;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 768px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  #clock {
    top: 15%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="clock">
  <div class="time hours">
    <div class="column">
      <div class="bit blank"></div>
      <div class="bit blank"></div>
      <div class="bit h5"></div>
      <div class="bit h4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="bit h3"></div>
      <div class="bit h2"></div>
      <div class="bit h1"></div>
      <div class="bit h0"></div>
    </div>
    <h2 class="display"></h2>
  </div>
  <div class="time minutes">
    <div class="column">
      <div class="bit blank"></div>
      <div class="bit m6"></div>
      <div class="bit m5"></div>
      <div class="bit m4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="bit m3"></div>
      <div class="bit m2"></div>
      <div class="bit m1"></div>
      <div class="bit m0"></div>
    </div>
    <h2 class="display"></h2>
  </div>
  <div class="time seconds">
    <div class="column">
      <div class="bit blank"></div>
      <div class="bit s6"></div>
      <div class="bit s5"></div>
      <div class="bit s4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="bit s3"></div>
      <div class="bit s2"></div>
      <div class="bit s1"></div>
      <div class="bit s0"></div>
    </div>
    <h2 class="display"></h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just change the CSS

```
#clock {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  top: 25%;
  margin: 0 auto 36px auto;
}
.time {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}
```

fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/Jim_Miraidev/axtdswb1/1/

Comment: this isn't responding to the window width. i want the squares to shrink to fit (still all next to each other) as the pages goes smaller

Comment: your .bit class has a width set  on them so you could do them as a percentage and set a max width , somthing like this - https://jsfiddle.net/Jim_Miraidev/axtdswb1/2/

Comment: another way is to use @media queries